Custom response in Business Central API
In Business Central (SaaS, version 24), I have developed a custom API page that provides tailored endpoints for my application needs. Currently, both the GET and POST methods are operating smoothly, allowing me to retrieve and send data as intended.
Now, I am seeking guidance on how to configure the API responses to ensure they are delivered to the caller in a specific format that meets our requirements.
Success
    {
    "Code" = 1,
    "message" = Success
    }
    
    Fails
    {
    "Code" = 0,
    "message" = Check xyz
    }


I think you need to create unbound action using codeunit to create a custom
here is an example from Microsoft documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-creating-and-interacting-with-odatav4-unbound-action
    codeunit 50100 "MiscOperations"
    {
    procedure Ping(input: Integer): Integer
    begin
        exit(-input);
    end;
 
    procedure Delay(delayMilliseconds: Integer)
    begin
        Sleep(delayMilliseconds);
    end;
 
    procedure GetLengthOfStringWithConfirmation(inputJson: Text): Integer
    var
        c: JsonToken;
        input: JsonObject;
    begin
        input.ReadFrom(inputJson);
        if input.Get('confirm', c) and c.AsValue().AsBoolean() = true and input.Get('str', c) then
            exit(StrLen(c.AsValue().AsText()))
        else
            exit(-1);
    end;
}


I receive as shown below.
{
"error": {
"code": "Application_DialogException",
"message": "Testing..  CorrelationId:  6e474882-bcf1-4614-b7af-bbb9ce6cc342."
}
}
I can handle the message part, which is good, but I also need to show error code 0 or 1 as needed.

Can you share the code, I think this is because you are giving error message in the api this requires UI so you are getting this error. Instead you can return something like this {“error”: “error message”, “status”:0}

I added some validations that generate an error message, which is expected. Can I change the error code without using an unbound API?

I believe it is not possible right now, and we need to wait for a while.
